# Is it possible to set a maximum node width in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like these two nodes to be the same size -- the size of the smaller one. In essence I'd like to be able to set `maximum size=6mm` but there is no such option. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{mystyle}=[circle,minimum size=6mm,draw=black,fill=white]
    \node (9) at (0,0) [mystyle] {9};
    \node (10) at (1,0) [mystyle] {10};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Although there's no `maximum size` key, you can use `text width` (and also possibly `inner sep`) to get the desired result:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
mystyle/.style={
  circle,
  inner sep=0pt,
  text width=6mm,
  align=center,
  draw=black,
  fill=white
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (9) at (0,0) [mystyle] {9};
    \node (10) at (1,0) [mystyle] {10};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Another option would have been to choose a larger value for `minimum size`, such as `minimum size=8mm`.

I changed the old `\tikzstyle` syntax for the more appropriate `\tikzset`. syntax.

Comment: This helps, but doesn't actually fix the problem in my case.

Answer (score 14):

An alternative solution could be to fix a `minimum size`, but to write
node's contents with a centered label. `labels` are drawn with a `postaction` and they don't influence on node's size:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{mystyle}=[circle,minimum size=6mm,draw=black,fill=white]
    \node[mystyle] (9) at (0,0) {9};
    \node[mystyle, label=center:10] (10) at (1,0) {};
    \node[mystyle, label=center:100] (100) at (2,0) {};
    \node[mystyle, label=center:1000] (1000) at (3,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my block diagram, I have one style set for ordinary short text node; and another one for long text node. This is because `center` issue.

```
mylong/.style={
  draw,
  rectangle,
  text width=20mm, % text is longer than 20mm.
  thick,
  % align=center,
  font=\itshape
},
myshort/.style={
  draw,
  rectangle,
  minimum size=6mm,
  thick,
  % align=center,
  font=\itshape
}
```

The result is acceptable, although it is not strict within 20mm (depends on how people see it).

Comment: dear @Tiina, how your answer address op question?

Comment: @Zarko I was looking for a solution for maximum too. And then I finally used a different style for the aberrant nodes.