# Make node size independent of content?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13588/38199) mentioned that the size of a node usually depends on the size of the content. For instance in following example the circle will have size `2cm` as long as the content doesn't force it to make it bigger. Is it possible then to set the size of this circle to a fixed value that is *independent* of the size of the content? (So a too large content might possibly overflow.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw node[fill,circle,minimum size=2cm] {content};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: using a label with centering would overflow -- note that the text within braces is not used

Comment: @jsbibra  ? It *is* used, it's just the same color of the fill. Try `fill=yellow`... BTW, nice trick for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
         \node[fill,circle,minimum size=2cm,label=center:\Huge content] {};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice trick this one!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  So just to clarify, is it true that whenever I use the `label=...` instead of the `{}` to define the content, the node will be sized as if there was no content at all?

Comment: @flawr -- this is not a new answer -- already answered here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414900/197451 --if you clarify the exact requirement probably a more detailed answer follows

Comment: I don't think I can add anything, this completely answers everything I wanted to know! thank you very much!